# who send SIGINT to foreground process when press ctrl+c, tty driver or shell

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, signals, sigint

When I press ctrl+c while a login shell is executing commands, the foreground process gets killed.
Who sends the signal?

Does TTY-driver send SIGINT to foreground process group directly?
Or does the TTY-driver send SIGINT to shell and shell redirects the signal to foreground process group?

Comment: The kernel doesn't care about "shells". A shell is just another process as far as the kernel is concerned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tty driver (specifically the line discipline) will send the signal directly to the foreground process group. Here's the code [from Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/359c92c02bfae1a6f1e8e37c298e518fd256642c/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L1116), where you can see that it simply gets the foreground group and signals it:

```c
/**
 *  [...]
 *      Called when a signal is being sent due to terminal input.
 *  [...]
 */

static void __isig(int sig, struct tty_struct *tty)
{
        struct pid *tty_pgrp = tty_get_pgrp(tty);
        if (tty_pgrp) {
                kill_pgrp(tty_pgrp, sig, 1);
                put_pid(tty_pgrp);
        }
}
```

This is invoked from the input processing function in the same file,  where `n_tty_receive_signal_char` is just a few short hops from invoking `__isig`:

```c
/**
 *  [...]
 *  Process an individual character of input received from the driver.
 *  This is serialized with respect to itself by the rules for the
 *  driver above.
 *  [...]
 */

static int
n_tty_receive_char_special(struct tty_struct *tty, unsigned char c)
{
    struct n_tty_data *ldata = tty->disc_data;

    /* [...] */

    if (L_ISIG(tty)) {
        if (c == INTR_CHAR(tty)) {
            n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGINT, c);
            return 0;
        } else if (c == QUIT_CHAR(tty)) {
            n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGQUIT, c);
            return 0;
        } else if (c == SUSP_CHAR(tty)) {
            n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGTSTP, c);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how can tty driver know the process group id of foreground process. Shell is the parent of these foreground process, only parent knows these information.

Comment: The shell informs the kernel of what the foreground process group is with `tcsetpgrp(3)`. In addition to directing signals, this is what allows the tty driver to stop background jobs that try to consume tty input. See the [Implementing a Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Foreground-and-Background.html) part of the GNU documentation.

Comment: got, thanks very very much, it is now very clearly.